# Can't run certain fullscreen applications

Tags: opensuse, x11, graphics, dwm

I have a dual screen setup which I've configured by running this command at startup:

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --auto --right-of DVI-0
```

I'm running `OpenSuse 11.4` with `dwm` as my window manager. I can post the output of any command or dump any file if you think it will help.

The problem happens when I try and run a fullscreen game. My right screen goes black and loses the signal. On the other screen, my resolution goes down and I see a magnified version of the upper left corner of my desktop (the dwm tag bar). I can hear the game audio but I can't see anything other than what I described above.

Another important thing is when this happens I need to reboot (or at least restart X) because I get no input and can't close anything.

**EDIT 1**

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Juniper [Radeon HD 5750 Series]
```

I'm not sure how I can find what driver I'm using, but I expect it's opensuse's stock driver. When the issue happens, I can't see my mouse at all -- even if I try and move it to the upper left. Pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F1` drops me to a command line login. Once I enter my information I can hear the audio again but I am in still the CLI. `Alt+SysReq+S` does nothing at all.

**EDIT 2**

After running the game and getting "locked up", I hit `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and was brought to a shell. I logged in and ran my display command and received the following error message:

```
X Error of failed request BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request: 150 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request: 7 (RRSetScreenSize)
  Serial number of failed request: 40
  Current serial number in output stream: 41
```

It looks like it's saying I've mistyped it or something, however I tried a couple times and I'm fairly certain my syntax was correct. I still tried going back to X with `Ctrl+Alt+F7` and I was stuck in the same situation. I then went back to the console and killed the game's process, and went back to X to see what happened. The resolutions and screens were still messed up, however I had mouse and keyboard support and could use my browser.

Comment: What graphics adapter do you have (post the relevant line from `lspci`)? What driver are you using? How did you check that you can't input anything: does the mouse cursor still move, does anything happen when you press `Ctrl+Alt+F1`, does anything happen when you press `Alt+SysRq+S` (it should cause some brief disk access)?

Comment: @Gilles: I've added info to my post.

Comment: Ok, so your keyboard isn't locked up, it's probably only a display bug. If you run `DISPLAY=:0 xrandr --output VGA-0 --auto --right-of DVI-0` from the command line you get after `Ctrl+Alt+F1` (log in first if necessary), then switch back to X with `Ctrl+Alt+F7`, what do you see?

Comment: @Gilles: Added another edit

Comment: Thanks for the data. I have no idea why `xrand` isn't working. The loss of keyboard and mouse may be due to a bad [grab](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23164/manipulating-x-key-and-pointer-grabs-on-the-command-line), or it may be due to something else.

Comment: Is it possible that my open source ATI driver isn't performing to the maximum? I've even tried playing games like Minecraft and it is very slow (even though I have hardware that can easily run it quickly).

Comment: The open source driver is almost certainly underperforming on any reasonably current adapter. You trade ease of installation and stability for performance and sometimes capabilities.

Comment: @Gille: good to know, now I'll try to get the non-free driver installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up being able to fix the issue by installing `fglrx` from the SuSE repositories. It seemed some capabilities (acceleration) were not supported in the open source version of the driver.