# Command for forcing a pointer ungrab (captured mouse release)

Tags: command-line, xorg, firefox, mouse

Sometimes Firefox doesn't release the mouse after dragging, so I need to kill the application to force it to release its pointer grab.

Is there any command to force an application to ungrab the pointer without killing it?

Comment: If you have the command line you can try to disable and re-enable the mouse. See [this wiki page](http://wpkg.org/Disable_/_enable_keyboard_and_mouse_in_Linux). I'm not sure it works, especially if the reason for the freeze is related to a Javascript issue.

Comment: @Guandalino: I have command line (By opening another terminal by pressing Alt+F2); I will test this in the next occurrence of the problem, Thanks

Comment: This is called a grab. [As far as I know, there is no command-line utility to manipulate grabs](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23164/manipulating-x-key-and-pointer-grabs-on-the-command-line).

Comment: I started having this problem with Firefox 13, and a web search brought me to this question. Are you by any chance using the Tree Style Tabs extension? It seems to be some problem with dragging tabs.

Comment: @Juliano: I didn't used Tree Style tabs ext. ! And Up now I didn't seen problem again so I didn't tried solutions too.

Comment: Can the pointer grabbing problem described here and the problem described as "pointer not moving anymore" there have the same source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/830099 , https://bugs.launchpad.net/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1035208 , https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1037586 . With that problem, switching to another linux virtual console and back to X helped. Does switching virtual consoles help with "grabbing"?

Comment: It also happened to me using OpenShot while dragging an audio track. Freezed the XFCE4 session for minutes and I had to kill OpenShot to use again my right or left click.

Answer (score 60):

On modern-ish X.org installations, there is an `XF86Ungrab` keysym, which causes the server to release all active pointer or keyboard grabs. You can make the server break all grabs by enabling break action XKB option, then generating the keysym either with a command or with the keyboard. With [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml):

```
setxkbmap -option grab:break_actions
xdotool key XF86Ungrab
```

On some systems, the `XF86Ungrab` keysym is bound to the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Keypad /</kbd>. However this possibility is often turned off [because it could allow bypassing a screensaver](http://who-t.blogspot.fr/2012/01/xkb-breaking-grabs-cve-2012-0064.html)).

Comment: Do I have to run the above command every time, or at every boot, or just once?

Comment: @AaronFranke Run this command when the problem occurs.

Comment: This answer saved me!  on Debian 11 with XFCE4.  I *think* mouse was captured by VirtualBox but am not 100% sure.  Thank you.

Comment: $.02 KDE by default maps Ctrl-Alt-KPDiv to XF86Ungrab (which doesn't do anything unless grab breaking is enabled, which is that setxkbmap option). Break out of grab can be (permanently) enabled in Input Devices -> Keyboard -> Advnaced -> Compatibility Options. And xkill is great for testing if grab breaking works.

Comment: Thanks, very useful solution for this Xfce bug to avoid restarting the session (tested on Debian 11):
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50426/xfce-hangs-with-hand-cursor

Answer (score 9):

I [answered this on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/540385/34598), and am quoting it here:

> [As Gilles noted,] In fact, it is possible to do this (at least with recent versions of
>   X).
>
> You can do this by pressing the <kbd>XF86Ungrab</kbd> key, introduced
>   in [this
>   commit](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/commit/?id=7d2543a3cb3089241982ce4f8984fd723d5312a1).
>
> By default, this keysym is not bound to any physical key or key
>   combination (it was disabled in 2012 after it was reported as a
>   security hole, since it allows anyone to bypass lock screens by
>   breaking their grabs). On some other setups it is bound to a shortcut
>   that uses the number pad. Obviously, that won't work on laptops that
>   lack a keypad.
>
> But you can still activate the keysym using `xdotool`:
>
> ```
> xdotool key XF86Ungrab
> ```
>
> This works with X.org version 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.8 on Ubuntu Precise.

Answer (score 0):

This may be like killing a fly with a hammer, but my desperate solution was to just use [htop](https://htop.dev/) to locate and kill the program that locked up my mouse pointer. Sorry, after writing this, I noticed your question explicitly says "without killing it".

**Background:**

I had the same issue happen to me in [File-Roller](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/FileRoller). I tried to extract a file within an archive by dragging it to [PCManFM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCManFM) in [Awesome Window Manager](https://awesomewm.org/). My mouse pointer changed to a grab-pointer-icon, and I couldn't click on anything. It was so frustrating.

**Steps to Kill Process:**

1. **Launch Terminal** - Hit the hotkeys for launching a terminal, which are `super+enter` in Awesome, but are typically `ctrl+alt+t` in most desktop environments.
2. **Run htop** - type "htop" (without quotes) and press enter.
3. **Find the Process** - In my case, I pressed F3 and typed "roller"
   (without quotes). This located and selected the file-roller process.
4. **Kill The Process** - Press F9 and select "SIGTERM" to kill the process.

This may not be the best way to do it, but it worked for me and it is easy to remember in a pinch.

Answer (score -9):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> will release mouse focus in most situations.

Comment: Sorry I'd like to understand better, is this a linux specific thing or firefox?

Comment: Linux, not completely sure, but i think it is a xorg function. I use it often to release focus from fullscreen videogames.

Comment: I doubt that this work; it is a single modifier plus a key, these combinations are used for applications (e.g. firefox activates "Find" box with this) and not for something like X (X uses keys like Alt+Ctrl+Backspace)! after that I tried it in a normal drag and drop and nothing happened!

Comment: That is not the case in any version of Firefox that I've seen, and it is definitely not the case “in most situations”: many applications use `Ctrl+G` for their own purposes, there is no such X-wide binding.