# Debug lost mouse clicks in Xserver

Tags: x11, xorg

i am using i3 on ArchLinux and from time to time, I can not reproduce what causes this, the Xserver is not processing the click events of my mouse. Apparently, the mouse events are correctly processed by the kernel and libinput as `libinput debug-events` shows this:

```
-event4   POINTER_BUTTON          +2.116s   BTN_LEFT (272) pressed, seat count: 1
 event4   POINTER_BUTTON          +2.212s   BTN_LEFT (272) released, seat count: 0
 event4   POINTER_BUTTON          +2.268s   BTN_LEFT (272) pressed, seat count: 1
 event4   POINTER_BUTTON          +2.356s   BTN_LEFT (272) released, seat count: 0
```

But nothing is happening inside `xev`.

However, the mouse movement event seem to be processed correctly as I can move it on the screen.

Thanks!

Comment: So program is likely grabing button events. See this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62252/77280) for how to figure out which process is responsible