# Force a specific button release

Tags: mouse, profile, xbindkeys

I've looked at this post, but it's not quite what I was looking for.

[Command for forcing a pointer ungrab (captured mouse release)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40458)

I want to fake the "Easy-Shift" functionality of my "Roccat XTD" on a "Bazalias X1" transformer mouse using xbindkeys.

Basically, I created two profiles that I want to swap depending on whether I `pressed` or `released` the mouse button.

The problem is that once any button is pressed, the click event jams, so no other click events go through.

Is there a way I could do this work flow:

1. Mouse `m:8` (finger down)
2. Load `~/.xbindkeys_config/speed_c/Profile2`
3. Force Release `m:8` (still holding the button)
4. Perform any clicks using `Profile2`
5. Mouse `m:8 + release` (finger up)
6. Load `~/.xbindkeys_config/speed_c/Profile1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I settled with "on click", switch profiles.
Here are my profile files.

**Profile1**

```bsh
#Switch Profile
"killall xbindkeys; xbindkeys -f ~/.xbindkeys_config/speed_c/Profile2"
b:8

#
# End of xbindkeys configuration
```

**Profile 2**

```bsh
#M Volume Up
"amixer -q set Master 2dB+ unmute"
b:4

#M Volume Down
"amixer -q set Master 2dB- unmute"
b:5

#M Copy
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key c' 'keyup Control_L'"
b:1

#M Paste
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key v' 'keyup Control_L'"
b:3

#M Undo
"xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key z' 'keyup Control_L'"
b:9

#Switch Profile-Copy
"killall xbindkeys; xbindkeys -f ~/.xbindkeys_config/speed_c/Profile1"
b:8

#
# End of xbindkeys configuration
```

Answer (score 0):

I think newer `xbindkeys` (1.8.3 or so) can reload its configuration on changes. If replacing the configuration file is possible, it might provide better performance than restarting `xbindkeys` each time.