# Why does clicking by mouse or touchpad sometimes stop working?

Tags: mouse, window-manager, touchpad, lxde, openbox

I am using Lubuntu 18.04.

For several times in the past few months, when I am using Firefox to browse webpages or some other applications, clicking ( left, right and middle)  by  my mouse or touchpad stops working. It is as if there were something else which is invisible, stands between the screen and the Firefox or other application's window, and steals clicks away.   I can still move the cursor using my mouse or touchpad, and I can still use my keyboard to type any key and to switch to other application's window (via Alt + Tab).

In that situtation, if I  log into another user's session without logging out the current one, the problem doesn't exist in the other user's session. But if I then switch back to the previous session of the original user, the problem remains.

What may cause the problem? It is unlikely the drivers or modules for the mouse or touchpad, since clicking  after switching to another user's session still works. Can the cause come from the window manager `openbox`, `lxsession`, or something else?

How shall I solve the problem?
Any solution resulting in closing the current applications' windows, e.g. restarting Lubuntu or logging out the current session, is the least thing I want to try.

Thanks.

Comment: This is too vague. The _thing_ that may stay between the clicks and the apps may be a passive grab -- google for "x11 release all grabs", and see if that fixes it without having to logout/login.

Comment: @mosvy Thanks. Do you mean https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40472/674? I just ran the two commands there `setxkbmap -option grab:break_actions` and
`xdotool key XF86Ungrab`, and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @mosvy   I can still use my keyboard to switch to another application's window and type any key without a problem

Comment: @mosvy I ran `xdotool key XF86Ungrab` for a second time, it seems to solve the problem. Not sure why.

Comment: A way to debug it would be to look which app (if any) is grabbing any mouse button may be with `xdotool key XF86LogGrabInfo` which will print some info in `/var/log/Xorg.$DISPLAY.log` (look for `grab.*Button`).

Comment: If talking about hw, it would be useful specifying brand of model of the notebook. Lenovo?