# Is there any way to identify which application is hijacking a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

Some application on my system (Ubuntu Linux 13.0) is hijacking a specific keyboard shortcut (`Ctrl+Space`). I don't know which one it is and would like to identify it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your core question was the main point of [Manipulating X key and pointer grabs on the command line](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23164/manipulating-x-key-and-pointer-grabs-on-the-command-line) for which I didn't find an answer that actually worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ibus is known to do this (at least on 14.04)

see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1278569

Comment: Thanks, that was it (though it doesn't answer my question directly).