# Problems Using Microsoft Sculpt Keyboard with Fedora

Tags: fedora, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I've been using the Microsoft Sculpt keyboard for about a week with almost no issue. The one problem I'm seeing is that the `Ctrl+F` keyboard combo doesn't seem to work anywhere in my OS, other shortcuts like `Ctrl+C` work everywhere, it's just this one key combo that doesn't appear to be working.

I ran `xev` to see what they keyboard was sending and when pressing just Ctrl I see:

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1800001,
    root 0x2cf, subw 0x0, time 1925315667, (906,904), root:(2921,1063),
    state 0x10, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

When I press just the F key I see:

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1800001,
    root 0x2cf, subw 0x0, time 1925295460, (906,904), root:(2921,1063),
    state 0x10, keycode 41 (keysym 0x66, f), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (66) "f"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (66) "f"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

When both are pressed I see:

```
 FocusIn event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1800001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  0   0   0   0   32  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

This doesn't seem to be the right output. Is there a simple way to fix this, or an easy way to map `Ctrl+F` to a function key that I'm not using?

Comment: The most likely explanation is that [some application has grabbed the key: check that](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23164/manipulating-x-key-and-pointer-grabs-on-the-command-line/62254#62254). Does Ctrl+F work in a text console? on another account? with a different keyboard?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work anywhere in the OS, in Chrome, Atom, or gedit. I was using a different Logitech keyboard previously and had no issue at all.